# Re-looping my question back to original input on python?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

This could be pretty obvious, but my mind is a blur from triyng to learn python all weekend. I understand the basics of the if/else statements from JS, but how do create a loop so if the question one input is no, the user is forced to go back to question 1 via a loop?

```
# initial input
question1 = input("Would you like to check the next UK Bank Holiday? [Yes/No?] ")
#next input
if question1.lower() == 'yes':
    print('Let\'s get started')
#if input is no 
elif question1.lower() == 'no':
    print('That is all the code does, please answer yes or no')
## do i need to create the input again here?
```

```
if question1.lower() == 'yes':
    print('Let\'s get started')
#if input is no 
elif question1.lower() == 'no':
    print('That is all the code does, please answer yes or no')
## do i need to create the input again here?
```